# Recursion for matrix in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion, matrix

I'm using recursion for finding neighbors of neighbors in a matrix (in a minesweeper game).  Right now my function is finding and marking neighbors only from left till bottom right.  What am I doing wrong?

**Javascript:**

```
function openAllZeroCount(elcell, i, j) {
    for (var idxi = i - 1; idxi <= i + 1; idxi++) {

        for (var idxj = j - 1; idxj <= j + 1; idxj++) {
            if (idxi < 0 || idxi >= gSize || idxj < 0 || idxj >= gSize) continue;
            if (gBoard[idxi][idxj].isMine === false && gBoard[idxi][idxj].minesAroundCount === 1) {

                var elCountZero = document.getElementById('cell-' + idxi + '-' + idxj)
                elCountZero.style.opacity = '0.8'
                elCountZero.innerText = gBoard[idxi][idxj].minesAroundCount
            }
            if (gBoard[idxi][idxj].isMine === false && gBoard[idxi][idxj].minesAroundCount === 0) {
                var elCountZero = document.getElementById('cell-' + idxi + '-' + idxj)
                elCountZero.style.opacity = '0.8'
            }
        }
    }
    if (idxi < 0 || idxi >= gSize || idxj < 0 || idxj >= gSize) return;
    if (gBoard[idxi][idxj].isMine === false) {

        console.log('gboard i j:', gBoard[idxi][idxj])

        openAllZeroCount(null, idxi, idxj)
    }
}
```

Comment: The recursive call would have to be inside your for loops. Right now you're calling it at the end of the function, which means at that point `idxi` and `idxj` are pointing to the cell to the right and down.

Comment: i know, if im putting it inside of the for loops im getting:
"general.js:103 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" should have been some condition that i cant figure out :S

Comment: Your code doesn't update `minesAroundCount` which means it tries to uncover the same fields over and over again, ad infinitum.

Comment: Sorry, the neighbor mine count doesn't change obviously; I meant `.covered` or similar of course, but I guess you figured that anyway.

Comment: i`m looking for the right condition for the function and i dont know how to put it out and where it need to call it.
 i need something "if(minesAroundCount===0){openAllZeroCount(elcell, i, j}    sorry for the text issues :S